# Is the minimum of two measurable functions measurable?

Tags: real-analysis

1.Is this generally true?

2.In Stein, when he is trying to prove the Fatou lemma, he uses following facts.
$\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of measurable functions with $f_n \geqslant 0$, $f_n$ tends to $f$ almost everywhere and $g$ is a bounded function supported on a set $E$ of finite measure. $0 \leqslant g \leqslant f$. Then he claims that $min(g,f_n)$ is measurable, and supported on $E$.

I do not see why this claim is true. Suppose that $g(x) \neq 0$, $i.e. x \in E$, then how does it imply that $min(g,f_n) \neq 0$. I only see it is true, when he considers sufficiently large $n$ such that $g \leqslant f_n$ for some $x$ guaranteed by Egorov's theorem.

Comment: "Supported on $E$" does not mean "whose support is *exactly* $E$;" it means "whose support is a subset of $E$."

Comment: But according to Stein, $f$ is supported on a set $E$, If $f(x) = 0$ whenever $x \notin E$

Comment: Yes. And that is true: if the $\operatorname{supp}(f) = \{ x: f(x) \neq 0\}$ is a subset of $E$, i.e. $\operatorname{supp}(f)\subseteq E$, then for any $x\notin E$ you have $f(x)=0$. This does not require $\operatorname{supp}(f)=E$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The minimum of two measurable functions is indeed measurable.  Indeed, if $f,g:X\to\mathbb{R}$ are measurable, then $(f,g):X\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is measurable, and then $\min(f,g)$ is just the composition of $(f,g)$ with the continuous function $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ taking a pair of numbers to its minimum.  Alternatively, you can just note that if $F=\min(f,g)$ then $F^{-1}((-\infty,r))=f^{-1}((-\infty,r))\cup g^{-1}((-\infty,r))$ is measurable.

To say that a function is "supported on $E$" usually means only that its support is *contained* in $E$, i.e. that it vanishes off of $E$.  It doesn't mean that the function is actually nonzero everywhere on $E$.  So it is clear that $\min(g,f_n)$ vanishes off of $E$, which is all that is being asserted here.

Comment: But according to Stein, $f$ is supported on a set $E$, If $f(x) = 0$ whenever $x \notin E$

Comment: Yes, that's only a one-way implication.  It doesn't mean that whenever $f(x)=0$, $x\not\in E$.

Comment: Oh, I see. But for the first one, do you have another proof? Stein has not talked about measurability for functions defined on $R^n, n\geqslant0$ yes.

Comment: I've added a more direct proof.

Comment: @Keith Are you sure? From the copy I have, this looks like Property 2, p. 29 -- way before Fatou's lemma.

Comment: He only allows functions defined on $R^d$ rather than functions taking value on $R^d$. @ClementC.